# npm broken global link - osx

Tags: macos, npm

I have a broken npm link on OSX that was created using the `npm link` command.  I was doing some testing and forgot to unlink the package before I deleted it.

When I do a `npm ls -g` I get the following error:

> `error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/package-test`

I've tried every solution that I have found, npm or osx specific but have been unable to remove the dead link.  Until recently the broken link wasn't a problem but recently I can no longer run

```
npm outdated -g
```

without getting an error.  Something changed in the last two days on npm and now the command fails because it can't find package in the repository.

Comment: Have you tried running [`npm cache clean`](https://docs.npmjs.com/troubleshooting/try-clearing-the-npm-cache) to clear the npm cache?

Comment: yep tried that.  also npm unlink, unlink <link>. rm <link> and I'm sure others